# PHP + mySQL + Pdo Query Speed Performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I was wondering if I could speed up a batch of queries by preparing the the Pdo outside the function like this:

```
$before = microtime(true);

// note this line
$query=$dbh->prepare("SELECT something FROM test WHERE record=:param");


for ($i=0 ; $i<1000 ; $i++) {
    callMe("worldcup2014");
}

function callMe($param) {
  global $dbh, $query;
  $query->bindParam(':param', $param);
  $query->execute();
  $result = $query -> fetch();
}

$after = microtime(true);
echo ($after-$before) . " sec\n";
```

And it is slightly faster than preparing inside the function like this:

```
$before = microtime(true);

for ($i=0 ; $i<1000 ; $i++) {
    callMe("worldcup2014");
}

function callMe($param) {
  global $dbh;

  // line is now here inside function
  $query=$dbh->prepare("SELECT something FROM test WHERE record=:param");

  $query->bindParam(':param', $param);
  $query->execute();
  $result = $query -> fetch();
}

$after = microtime(true);
echo ($after-$before) . " sec\n";
```

The first example takes about 0.61 secs, sometimes 0.60 secs

The second example takes about 0.65secs, never less than 0.63 secs.

I know it is a minor difference, but are there any other things that should be considered to speed up Pdo queries ? Note: I can't store/cache results. Need to grab fresh data.

Comment: how about adding indexes

Comment: sorry, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=database+index

Comment: table is already indexed

Comment: Thats micro optimization. Your table structure, database server & connection will have a way larger impact on your performance than the differences in your two code examples. I'd only look deeper into that if this really does any significant impact on an application, p.e. while executing this code part a few million times or so.

Comment: You execute the same damn query all the time. It IS cached anyway. The difference is probably CPU time due to the different number of instructions... Please use a different query all the time to get more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of the benefits of using prepared queries is performance improvement. If you're going to execute the same query many times, you should prepare it just once, then execute it repeatedly. Preparing a query requires a call to the database, and this is expensive.

You can improve it a little more by only calling `bindParam` once. `bindParam` binds to a variable reference, so all you have to do is reassign the variable and call `execute()`, you don't have to bind the variable again. However, this won't work when you're executing the query in a function as you are, because each time you enter the function you get a new version of the parameter variable, and the reference doesn't persist between function calls.

So it should be like this pseudo-code:

```
prepare statement
bind parameter to $var
foreach ($array as $var) {
    execute
}
```

You could turn this into one query with something like this:

```
$in = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'));
$sql = "SELECT something FROM test WHERE record IN ($in)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This should be far more efficient than repeatedly querying.

Comment: It seems you didn't get the question. He isn't asking for explanations but for improvements. While running such a function in a loop is quite silly and useless

Comment: yep, just got less 0.01 to 0.02 :) ok @your common sense, I need to run a query with 1 always different param. 1000 loop is for benchmark purposes only

Comment: @YourCommonSense I assume the real application doesn't repeatedly use the same parameter value, that's just an example.

Comment: @Barmar that's why this "example" is bad.

Comment: @JackM. you have been told to run one query instead of a thousand already

Comment: I know what you mean and will take that into account. In this example the param is user input so if I had 1000 users inputing data, I would need 1000 queries I would guess

Comment: I've added an example showing how to do it in a single query.